# Proper URI syntax for referencing public resource file in DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, uri

Says it all...

I have an XAML Resource Dictionary file (text) in "Resources.resx" under the public class "Resources" accessible by the public method "Styles."

I can find the resource in the standard C# method under the DLL's namespace...

But my problem is when it comes to writing this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="????"></ResourceDictionary>
```

Everything I've tried for source causes a runtime exception error. So I apparently don't understand the syntax...  People keep putting a bunch of commas in these source paths... are they part of the syntax?

Or, is there a more proper method for including XAML resource files in class libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) that references a resources in an another assembly:

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml
```

In XAML you can omit the prefix and just write

```
<ResourceDictionary
    Source="/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"/>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completely forgot I had asked this already... Unfortunately this doesn't work for me and it's driving me absolutely crazy because everyone says it should work... I reposted this question with a lot more detail about it - if you have any ideas I'd be grateful - but I'll accept the answer here I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023754/add-a-wpf-xaml-resourcedictionary-to-a-dll

Comment: Do you have any idea if I should be able to see "resource" files in the object explorer of the referenced assembly?  Because I can't find the file that I have marked as "resource" in my class library in the DLL's object explorer...